# The listviewer not change select in onshow

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, items

how can I change a selected item in listview...

here is my code sample:

```
 for c := 0  to Form1.LV1.Items.count -1  do
    begin
      if  (form1.lv1.Items[c].SubItems.Objects[3] as TTabSheet).TabIndex = 
        pgc1.ActivePageIndex then
      begin
        form1.lv1.Items[c].Selected:= True;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code fails please

Comment: i need change the selected of item of listiewer  when the onshow of the tabsheet have a action !

Comment: Can you explain how your code fails please

Comment: the error in ListViewer is that not selecting this item when I action the onshow, i need select the index on listviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple application with a list view, set it into report mode, added some items, and added this `OnShow` event:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.Items[1].Selected := True;
end;
```

The specified item was indeed selected.

The conclusion that I draw from this is that the `Selected` property can be used from the `OnShow` event. Therefore, if your program does not result in the list view selection be set, it would seem that either:

1. The code in the question is not running at all, or
2. The code is running, but the `if` statement condition is never `True`.

Your next step is to debug your program. Inspect your program as it executes using your preferred debugging technique. The interactive debugger would be a sound choice.

Comment: thanks for all , the list view dont select onshow only in onchange !